# Need to select Maximum LAG_MIN for db_name in the entire week and count its occurrence for entire week

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Below is the SQL Query that selects maximum lag_min in past 24 hours.

```
WITH temp1 AS
(SELECT DISTINCT a.collection_timestamp,
round((a.value / 60),0)lag_min,
substr(b.target_name,1,instr(b.target_name,'.',1,1)- 1)db_name,
b.PROPERTY_VALUE DataGuardStatus,
c.PROPERTY_VALUE OpenMode
FROM sysman.mgmt_metrics_raw a,
SYSMAN.MGMT$TARGET_PROPERTIES b,
SYSMAN.MGMT$TARGET_PROPERTIES c
WHERE a.metric_guid = '52D41523BFF32FD2E50DB55B9E730E68'
AND round((a.value / 60),0)> 5
AND a.target_guid = b.target_guid AND b.target_guid=c.target_guid
AND (b.target_name NOT LIKE '%opd%' AND b.target_name NOT LIKE '%ope%' AND b.target_name NOT LIKE '%opt%' AND b.target_name NOT LIKE '%opl%')
AND b.PROPERTY_NAME='DataGuardStatus'
AND c.PROPERTY_NAME='OpenMode'
AND a.collection_timestamp > SYSDATE - 1
)
select collection_timestamp,
lag_min,
db_name,
OpenMode
from (
select collection_timestamp,
lag_min,
db_name,
OpenMode,
max(collection_timestamp) over (partition by db_name) max_col_time
from
(
select collection_timestamp,
lag_min,
db_name,
OpenMode,
max(lag_min) over (partition by db_name) max_lag_min
from temp1 where db_name is not NULL
)
where lag_min = max_lag_min
)
where collection_timestamp = max_col_time 
order by lag_min desc;
```

Output -->

```
COLLECTION_TIMESTAM    LAG_MIN DB_NAME    OPENMODE
------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------------------
2019-07-21 06:14:42        179 opp314a    MOUNTED
2019-07-21 03:01:08        178 ewp2c      READ ONLY WITH APPLY
2019-07-21 04:52:28         53 opp426a    MOUNTED
2019-07-20 10:44:05         40 opp219a    MOUNTED
2019-07-21 01:52:00         39 opp231a    MOUNTED
2019-07-21 00:40:17         27 opp302a    MOUNTED
2019-07-21 04:19:50         11 opp351a    READ ONLY WITH APPLY
2019-07-21 04:13:13         10 opp395a    MOUNTED
2019-07-21 04:14:58         10 opp422a    MOUNTED
```

9 rows selected.

Example If below is the DATA:

```
COLLECTION_TIMESTAM    LAG_MIN DB_NAME    OPENMODE
------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------------------
2019-07-21 06:14:42        179 opp314a    MOUNTED
2019-07-20 03:01:08        228 opp314a    MOUNTED
2019-07-19 04:52:28        167 opp314a    MOUNTED
2019-07-18 10:44:05         41 opp314a    MOUNTED
2019-07-21 01:52:00         39 opp231a    MOUNTED
2019-07-20 00:40:17         27 opp231a    MOUNTED
2019-07-19 04:19:50         11 opp231a    MOUNTED
```

I want the output as

```
COLLECTION_TIMESTAM    LAG_MIN DB_NAME    OPENMODE        COUNT
------------------- ---------- ---------- --------------- ------
2019-07-20 03:01:08        228 opp314a    MOUNTED         4 
2019-07-21 01:52:00         39 opp231a    MOUNTED         3
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to select maximum lag_min for db_name in the entire week and count its occurrence.

Comment: If I put sysdate-7 in the above query then it will give me the data for maximum lag_min in the entire week but I also want the count number of times it occurred.

Comment: you should use having ... see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075180/sql-oracle-12c-how-to-select-results-from-another-select-statement-nesting/57075242#57075242)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `max() over (partition by ...)` and `count() over (partition by ...)` analytic functions to `<your query>`

```
select collection_timestamp,lag_min,db_name,OpenMode,"COUNT"
  from 
  (
   select collection_timestamp,lag_min,db_name,OpenMode,
         max(lag_min) over 
            ( partition by db_name ) as lag_max,
         count(db_name)  over 
            ( partition by db_name ) as "COUNT"  
     from
     (
       <your_query>    
     )
   )
 where lag_max =  lag_min
 order by collection_timestamp;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f2d1b3385df2177bf73e21dba169b6c1)</kbd>